# api connect on-premises API Designer wants to connect to Bluemix not locally (Windows 10)

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

This is driving me nuts. I thought I had cracked this. I have one (admin) cmd window in which entering 'apic edit' opens a browser tab with url http://127.0.0.1:9000/#/design/apis for local use. However, in another (admin) window, the result of 'apic edit' is a tab with url http://127.0.0.1:9000/login.html which wants me to log in to Bluemix.

I found a suggested fix for this: ’set SKIP_LOGIN=true’, which I'm sure either solved the problem or was part of other things I found to get the editor working locally. But it doesn't work in a new cmd window. I have issed an 'apic login' to my local APIM (a VM), but apic still wants to go to Bluemix.

I must have done something else in the first window that makes it work locally, but I can't find out what. One difference is that after 'apic edit' in the 'good' window, the response is:

-^-^-

Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:9000
loopback deprecated loopback#context middleware is deprecated. See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Using%20current%20context for more details. C:\Apps\IBM\node\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\loopback\server\middleware\rest.js:60:32

-^-^-

Whereas for the 'bad' window, the response is only the first line "Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:9000"

The problems I am having, just to get started makeme wonder "why is this so difficult?". Yes, I know that I learn more this way, but... All help gratefully received.

Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

You should set the SKIP_LOGIN env variable in every cmd window you open.

You can use the command like this "SKIP_LOGIN=true apic edit" in every cmd window you open

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro Pérez Soria. I thought the problem was due to my typo (SKIP_LOGON=true by mistake). Even when corrected to SKIP_LOGIN=true, the Bluemix tab opens. I tried defining a local Bluemix but that doesn't help. It adds this to the local 'config' file:
UI_Default_Server:
  displayName: Local
  host: 192.168.1.2
  dedicated: true
  name: local
'Sign in Blumix' produces a non-existant url, which starts:
https://login-service-apiconnect.168.1.2/auth?redirectURL=...
This cmd window doesn't work, but the one created earlier does. I can't see a difference. Grrrr!

Comment: I have now started the Designer from the 'good' window and it works, even though the 'UI_Default_Server:' entry is still in the local config file. I can't work out what to make of this behaviour.